# Store and retrieve address/pointer to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

Let's say we have a char array:

```
char pool[1000];
```

and a pointer

```
char* ptr;
```

the pointer stores an address to a block of data in Pool. I want to store this address in the pool and retrieve it as well.

Basically, what I want to do is a linked-list that is embedded in the char array Pool. The reason is that i'm not allowed to create any new variables (globally), and I cant include new headers, among other restrictions.

**So the question is : how to I segment and fit a 4 byte address in (let's say) the first 4 elements of pool[] , and how do I retrieve it again for the purpose of modification.**

This operation will happen frequently so it needs to be fast...and of course not rely of external functions.

Comment: sounds like you want something similar to a stack allocator. how do you want to keep track of used portions of the pool?

Comment: Ref this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20945439/1870232

Comment: @P0W this is helpful. But I can't declare global variables, hence storing in pool.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yes, I'm making an allocator. Stack allocator won't do it for my scenario, so it's going to be some form of freestore allocator. I didn't get to the point of keeping track of the blocks yet. As you can see, I want to get past the storing and retrieving date first :) . But i'm open for suggestions in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

To store the value of `ptr` in `pool`, use:

```
memcpy(pool, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
```

To retrieve the value of the pointer from `pool`, use:

```
memcpy(&ptr, pool, sizeof(ptr));
```

Re:

> This operation will happen frequently so it needs to be fast...and of course not rely of external functions.

`memcpy` is exactly what you need. If you cannot use `memcpy`, you'll need to implement the exact functionality in your code.

Unless you are able to verify that the calls to `memcpy` is a performance bottleneck, I would advise using it.

Comment: I cant use it since it needs string.h/cstring . I will try writing it

Comment: so I have used this implementation for memcpy:
`code`
void myMemCpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t n)
  {
   // Typecast src and dest addresses to (char *)
   char *csrc = (char *)src;
   char *cdest = (char *)dest;

   // Copy contents of src[] to dest[]
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
    cdest[i] = csrc[i];
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
   }
  }
`code`

it works but it doesn't store the pointer in the array. It just set the pointer to the array address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store ptr in pool then should you have a pool of addresses instead?

```
char *pool[1000];
```

Then

```
pool[0] = ptr;
ptr = pool[0];
etc.
```

If you have to deal with a buffer of characters, that is

```
char pool[1000];
```

but treat it as a buffer of addresses then bend it by creating a local variable:

```
char **pp = reinterpret_cast<char**>(&pool);
*pp = ptr;
```

The later stores ptr at the start of the buffer pool. To retrieve it:

```
ptr = *pp;
```

You may move along the pool by incrementing the pointer `pp`

```
pp++ // next address
```

*And don't make an assumption that address is 4 bytes!*