# Create myNew/myDelete to replace new/new[]/delete/delete[]

Tags: c++, memory-management, maintainability

How to code my program to has flexibility to receive custom allocator in advance?

I coded some allocators, but not sure whether I will really need it.
 However, I know for sure that if my custom allocator will be plugged-in, I want to use it in some certain parts.

### **Example**

For example, `int* B::db` should use **custom allocator** (`myNew`/`myDelete`),
 while all `std::vector` should use **standard allocator**.

While I still don't plug my custom allocator, I wish my program will use standard `new/delete` as default.

```
#define myNew new
#define myDelete delete
class B{ //B should not be a template class
    int* db=nullptr;
    std::vector<float> something; //<- let it use default new/delete
    public: B(){
        db=myNew int[5];   //work like "db=new int[5];"
    }
    public: ~B(){
        myDelete[] db;     //work like "delete[] db;"
    }
};
```

If I want plug a custom allocator later, I can just change the `#define`.

**Note:** `B` should not be a template class.

### Question

I am not sure if this is a correct way.  I am still very new to allocator.
I also want to avoid macro if possible.
Is it a good solution?  Are there solutions without macro?

I can let my program just use `new/delete` as default, and I can refactor it later.
However, it will probably be a mental-breaking work in the future.

**Note:** Most Q/A seem to focus on overloading the global `new/delete`. That is not what I want. :-

- [overloading new/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete)
- [How to properly replace global new & delete operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186018/how-to-properly-replace-global-new-delete-operators)
- [Using operator new and operator delete with a custom memory pool/allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945439/using-operator-new-and-operator-delete-with-a-custom-memory-pool-allocator)

Sorry if this question is too newbie.
I haven't found any good tutorial/information about using allocator in *real* practice.

I have also read (they are just *theory* of allocator + code) :-

- https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/general-programming/c-custom-memory-allocation-r3010
- http://allenchou.net/2013/05/memory-management-part-3-of-3-stl-compatible-allocators/
- http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/improving-performance-with-custom-pool-a/184406243?pgno=1

Comment: Don't actually understand what you're asking

Comment: @Passer  Sorry to hear that.  In short, the question is "How to make a program to switch-on&off custom allocator easily?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B may have to stay a non-template. But it doesn't mean you can't write a template to help. And you may as well facilitate RAII while you're at it.

```
template<typename T>
class my_new_heap_array {
  T *ptr;
public:
  operator T*() const { return ptr; }

  my_new_heap_array(std::size_t sz) 
    : ptr(myNew T[sz])
  {}

  ~my_new_heap_array() { myDelete[] ptr; }
};

class B { //B should not be a template class
    my_new_heap_array<int> db;
    std::vector<float> something; //<- let it use default new/delete
    public:
    B()
      :db(5)
    { }
};
```

In general, so long as you program with separation of concerns in mind, you'd find it easier to change behaviors more easily. B needs to decide on what allocator to use, but it shouldn't be concerned with how to use it. That concern falls on the helper class. And if B needs to use another allocator some day, then just switch out the helper class for another.

Comment: It seems to be a right way, thank.     I have never seen any book do like this.  Where can I find more information / what is this technique call?

Comment: @javaLover - Mmmm, Iv'e been treating this as C++ folklore for so long I forgot where I first saw it. I think the general design principal of "separation of concerns" is the thing to note. If you find yourself thinking how you'd customize something in a class, it's usually a sign that your class is not the one that should be concerned with how it's done, but rather another utility class that is composed into your business logic. [/ramble].

Comment: Your speech is full of wisdom as always.  It makes me look all programming in a more modular way.  There are a lot of other things to think of, after I read your comment.  Thank.